# Netlogo - accessing patches or agents in lists?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of patches. I am using list instead of a patchset because the elements must remain ordered so can use it as a reference to create other lists. I'm looking to create lists of attributes of those patches, but "of" doesn't seem to work with lists.
Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
;; create list of patches in front of player
set map-area (list patch-at -1 1 patch-at 0 1 patch-at 1 1)
;; create list of grass levels in those patches
set grass-layer-map (list [grass-amount] of map-area)
;; create list of how many turtles in each patch
set turtle-layer-map (list [count turtles-here] of map-area)
```

This method (using "of") worked when I was using a patchset instead of a list, but now I get the following error:

> OF expected input to be a turtle agentset or patch agentset or turtle
>   or patch but got the list [(patch 2 4) (patch 3 4) (patch 4 4)]
>   instead.

I need to figure out a new way to get at those patch attributes and create new lists. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are manipulated with different primitives than agentsets. The NetLogo Dictionary has a specific section for list primitives. In your case, the equivalent of `of` is `map`.

This will work:

```
patches-own [grass-amount]

to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches
  [ set grass-amount random 3
    sprout 2
  ]
  let map-area (list patch -1 1 patch 0 1 patch 1 1)
  print map-area
  ;; create list of grass levels in those patches
  let grass-layer-map map [ p -> [grass-amount] of p ] map-area
  print grass-layer-map
  ;; create list of how many turtles in each patch
  let turtle-layer-map map [p -> [count turtles-here] of p ] map-area
  print turtle-layer-map
end
```

I'm thinking there should be a cleaner way of doing the map that doesn't use the anonymous function to access the patch's variable but I'm having a mental blank.